# OAuth2/Cognito: Let trusted server act on behalf of user

Tags: oauth2, jwt, api-gateway, aws-cognito, cognito

I'm building a public HTTP JSON API using API Gateway with ID token authentication.

I now need a server that acts on behalf of users. Users message that server using a third party (think Signal or WhatsApp) and the server calls some API methods on their behalf. That server knows which third party account the message is coming from and should check whether there is a Cognito user with that account in the user pool. (The third party isn't an identity provider, so we aren't using identity pools but are just storing an account id.)

How can I authenticate the server towards the API? Can I get an id token without the users credentials and without a refresh token but just with admin access to Cognito? Is this way of authentication secure?